# Spring Batch FlatFileItemWriter - delete temporary file after proessing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a FlatFileItemWriter in my spring batch running in a Spring Boot application. The writer creates the file in temp location and the file is FTPd from there. I need to delete the file after FTP. But deleting the file does not work. On normal windows delete it shows File is Open in Java(VM). I have to use `setAppend(true)` in my writer. Any idea how to resolve this?

Code

```java
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Model, Model> chunk(10)
            .reader(Reader())
            .processor(Processor())
            .writer(ItemWriter(ItemWriterClassifier()))
            .build();
}

public Step step2() {
  return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2").tasklet((contribution, chunkcontext) -> {
    FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File(path));
      return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
      }).build();
}

public Classifier<Model, ItemWriter<? super Model>> ItemWriterClassifier() {
  return Model -> {
        FlatFileItemWriter<Model> itemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        itemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(new File(path)));
        itemWriter.setAppendAllowed(true);
        itemWriter.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<Model>() {{
            setDelimiter(",");
            setFieldExtractor(FieldExtractor());
        }});

    itemWriter.open(new ExecutionContext());
    return itemWriter;
  };
}
```

Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\File_F.txt
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2400) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1721) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
    at com.bil.po.batch.DmsJob.lambda$0(DmsJob.java:119) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:66) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:136) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:308) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:141) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
```

Thanks

Comment: `deleting the file does not work.` when/how are you deleting the file? Are you using a step listener or a separate step to do the cleanup? Please share the code and the stacktrace of the error to be able to help you.

Comment: I was deleting the files insied a separate step using`FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File(path))`. Noticed that while the service is running I cannot even delete it normally using windows delete. It says file is currently in use by Java VM.

Comment: `Noticed that while the service is running I cannot even delete it normally using windows delete`: I'm not surprised by that. when the job is running, the JVM is still using the file so you can't remove it from a file explorer.

Comment: please edit the question and add the code there.